# how can i store,update and delete that image?

Tags: sql

I am doing a project related to Student information.Front-end tool is java And back-end tool is SQL.I want to place a image of student.how can i store,update and delete that image?

Answer (score 1):

You have to give a separate table for keeping the image details. You should have a folder in your server for keeping the image files. You can identify each file by giving the imageId as the filename which will be unique. There should be a column in student details that gets the image id for that particular student.

If the image is edited then update the imageID column in image table with the new details.

If it is deleted then remove the imageId from the student table.

**Keep images on the filesystem, and the location and other data in the database**